# Error : LEAK: ByteBuf.release() in grpc call

Tags: grpc-java

Hello Grpc Folks,

I am getting the following issue in grpc call :

```
LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See 
https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:363)
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
```

Any idea, whats this about?

Comment: This is about "memory leaks" i.e. not decrementing the ref-count in the gRPC code. You can run your application with ADVANCED or PARANOID level as described in https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#wiki-h2-9 to get more information about where leaks are occuring.

Comment: Yeah, do what San has mentioned to see where the leak was introduced in application code. Also, which gRPC version are you using? There may be recent bugfixes related to it, such as https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7105. Try upgrading to the latest release to see if the issue persists. If it does, please file an issue on Github including the full stacktrace with leak detection.